# how to know if storedproc executed successfully

Tags: java, database, stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to execute a stored proc in java.
I know I have to connect to database and do the stuff....
But the thing is How do I know that if that stored proc executed successfully?
Thanks.

Comment: "Successfully"?  If you mean "didn't crash" that's one thing.  If you mean "does the right thing to the right data", that's another thing.  Also, status reporting varies slightly from database to database.  What database are you using?  What do you mean by "successfully"?

Comment: I am using DB2.  I mean "does the right thing to the right data",

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a OUT parameter returning zero if everything goes fine? I would have `p_return_code` and `p_return_message` with the other input parameters.

When I make a proc call, I will set them to `0` and `Success` within the stored procedure and return them. Do as many data validation after insert/update/delete and finally set to success. I would also handle exceptions and return error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are wanting to check that it, "does the right thing to the right data" I'd say this is something you'd need to test while writing the proc...

Your stored proc will do whatever you tell it to, it has no way of determining if that what you "really" wanted it to do.  If you are trying to detect an error that's another story.

Can you describe a scenario in which it would execute with no errors but do the "wrong thing to the wrong data"?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I want to know the stored proc(assume its doing the right job) executed successfully with out any interruption.

Answer (score -1):

never forget to return a number in the procedure, eg. when everything ok return 0, if some other operation failed, return some other number and identify it with the error code you decide to use, eg. 1 - Insert failed